# Third-party gradle plugin built using java 8 and uses java.sql module, how to run it's tasks using jdk 11

Tags: java, gradle, java-8, java-11

I am trying to run task which is defined in third party gradle plugin. The problem is that in our project we are using jdk11 while the plugin itself is built with java 8. So, when I am trying to run the task from plugin I get the following error: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.Timestamp.`
I suppose that I need somehow to add this module ("java.sql") to the runtime when I am executing the task.
Is there a way to make gradle run tasks defined in plugin with specific jvm args, such as "--add-module java.sql" for example?
There is no way for us to lower java version to java-8.

I have tried to run the task defined in the plugin using java 8 like so:

`./gradlew scanMetamodel -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home`

but this also did not work:
 `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: <Some-class> has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.`

After that I have contacted the "third-party" who provided the plugin and asked them to provide me a version compiled with java-11 but the original problem still remains.

Comment: Your problem seems to be that the project has been compiled with a higher java version and now there are some class files present in the project folder that are accessed by `scanMetamodel`. Therefore you should execute `./gradlew clean` before executing gradle commands using Java 8. Then I would specify for the whole terminal to use Java 8 by setting the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` to your JDK8 path.

Comment: @Robert, the problem is that whole our project is made using java 11 features so we could not compile it with jdk 8 without errors.

Comment: They you have reached a dead end. The plugin used by `scanMetamodel` is not able to read class files compiled by Java 11. Usually it is a used asm byte code library that is used by the plugin that needs to be updated. BTW: Why don't you mention the used plugin? It is difficult to help you if you don't tell use the necessary data.

Comment: @Robert, unfortunately this plugin is not in the common access it is made inside my company and used only inside. Anyway, thank you for the response!